# Brother and sister fighting elemental guardians for elixir of life to save their sick father/king and his dying realm

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie in the late '80s or early '90s but it might be older. Atmosphere and visuals were similar to Eastern European or French fantasy movies of the '70s or even '60s.

It is a live-action children's movie. I think it was in colour, but everything was toned down or brownish, so that it felt or actually might be a black-and-white. Atmosphere and style reminded me very much of the Czech fantasy movies, e.g. [*The Little Mermaid* (1976)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_Mermaid_(1976_Czech_film))

The brother has a sword or rather a sabre fitting to his size. He has dark curly hair about chin length and ... dark trousers and a white shirt with quillings - similar to a pirate shirt.

The girl wears a simple dress.

Royal children, a brother about 10 years old and a sister about 6 years old, leave their home because their father - a king or some kind of lord - is ill, and as he is dying, so it is his realm. They have to get the blood of three creatures representing the elements air, water and ? to create an elixir of life. The creatures are never shown completely, but after the fight with the sea creature there is some kind of kraken tentacle washed ashore.

Apart from this I only remember an encounter with some kind of cat princess living in a haunted castle, who tries to lure the sister into some kind of trap - as far as I remember - and that in the end they are flying on some giant creature and disperse the elixir over the land... but that might be a false memory.